# How to display entire Text content from second text in android jetpack compose?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I am displaying some Text content with it's Title but my issue is that line of the text content is not getting displayed properly , it's showing like this [image]

So, i want the last line to be displayed fully , this is my code

```
import androidx.compose.foundation.background
import androidx.compose.foundation.gestures.detectTransformGestures
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.Column
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.Row
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.Spacer
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.fillMaxSize
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.fillMaxWidth
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.height
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.padding
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.width
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.wrapContentHeight
import androidx.compose.material.ExperimentalMaterialApi
import androidx.compose.material.FractionalThreshold
import androidx.compose.material.Text
import androidx.compose.material.rememberSwipeableState
import androidx.compose.material.swipeable
import androidx.compose.material3.Text
import androidx.compose.runtime.Composable
import androidx.compose.runtime.LaunchedEffect
import androidx.compose.runtime.getValue
import androidx.compose.runtime.mutableStateOf
import androidx.compose.runtime.remember
import androidx.compose.runtime.setValue
import androidx.compose.ui.Modifier
import androidx.compose.ui.graphics.Color
import androidx.compose.ui.input.pointer.pointerInput
import androidx.compose.ui.text.TextStyle
import androidx.compose.ui.text.font.FontFamily
import androidx.compose.ui.text.font.FontWeight
import androidx.compose.ui.text.input.TextFieldValue
import androidx.compose.ui.unit.dp
import androidx.compose.ui.unit.sp
import androidx.navigation.NavController
import com.example.speechrecognition.Destinations
import kotlin.math.absoluteValue

@OptIn(ExperimentalMaterialApi::class)
@Composable
fun SpeechScreen1(navController: NavController) {
var offsetX by remember { mutableStateOf(0f) }
val swipeThreshold = 200 // Adjust this threshold as needed
val maxOffsetX = 1000f // Adjust this value based on your needs

Column(
    modifier = Modifier
        .fillMaxWidth()
        .wrapContentHeight()
        .padding(21.dp, top = 100.dp)
        .pointerInput(Unit){
            detectTransformGestures { _, offset,_,_ ->
                offsetX +=offset.x
                if (offsetX.absoluteValue >=swipeThreshold){
                    if (offsetX>0){
                        navController.navigate(Destinations.speechscreen2)
                    }
                    offsetX =0f
                }
            }
        }
  ){
        Text(
        text = "Please read the following text:",
        style = TextStyle(
            fontSize = 20.sp,
            lineHeight = 28.sp,
            fontFamily = FontFamily.Serif,
            fontWeight = FontWeight(400),
            color = Color(0xFF000000)
        )
    )
    Text(
        text = "One morning Dorothy crossed the hall of the palace and knocked on the door of another girl named Trot. When told to enter, Dorothy found that Trot had company, an old sailor-man with a wooden leg who was sitting by the open window puffing smoke from a pipe.",
        style = TextStyle(
            fontSize = 32.sp,
            lineHeight = 40.sp,
            fontFamily = FontFamily.SansSerif,
            fontWeight = FontWeight(300),
            color = Color(0xFF080808)
        ),
        modifier = Modifier
            .width(334.dp)
            .height(440.dp)
            .padding(top = 9.dp)
    )

    Row(modifier = Modifier.padding(top = 27.dp)) {
        Row(
            modifier = Modifier
                .width(77.dp)
                .height(7.dp)
                .background(color = Color(0xFF686868))
                .padding(top = 26.dp)
        ) {
        }
        Spacer(modifier = Modifier.width(5.dp))
        Row(
            modifier = Modifier
                .width(77.dp)
                .height(7.dp)
                .background(color = Color(0xFFD9D9D9))
                .padding(top = 26.dp)
        ) {
        }
        Spacer(modifier = Modifier.width(5.dp))
        Row(
            modifier = Modifier
                .width(77.dp)
                .height(7.dp)
                .background(color = Color(0xFFD9D9D9))
                .padding(top = 26.dp)
        ) {
        }
        Spacer(modifier = Modifier.width(5.dp))
        Row(
            modifier = Modifier
                .width(77.dp)
                .height(7.dp)
                .background(color = Color(0xFFD9D9D9))
                .padding(top = 26.dp)
        ) {
        }
    }

}}
```

I have tried to put the text inside a Column but it's still not showing complete text

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not restrict height of `Text` instead you can use `.wrapContentHeight()` for the `modifier` of `Text` beacuase the static height is causing the text to cut due to restriction.